# Python alternative to import

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got the following code:

```
def main():
    #init
     #Load config.
    import localconfig
    print localconfig.name
     #update mac adress db, if at all possible:
    try:
        from maclist import maclist
    except:
        import urllib2
        print "Fetching MAC adress db."
        maclist = urllib2.urlopen(localconfig.url)
        fl = open("maclist.py","w")
        fl.write(
"#maclist.py generated by "+localconfig.name+"""
#Based on """+localconfig.url+"""
maclist = {}
""")
        print "Generating maclist.py"
        for line in maclist:
            if "#" in line: line=line[:line.index("#")]
            line = line.split()
            if line:
                if "-" in line[0]:
                    line[0]=line[0].replace("-",":")
                if "/" in line[0]:
                    ndex = line[0].index("/")
                    ndex = (int(line[0][ndex+1:])//8)*3
                    line[0]=line[0][:ndex-1]
                line=[repr(part) for part in line]
                line = "maclist["+line[0]+"]="+line[1]
                fl.write("=".join(line.split())+"\n")
        fl.close()
    from maclist import maclist
    print "Succesfully loaded maclist.py"
```

This does work, but I don't like the fact that I'm importing (and thus running) something I downloaded from the interweb. Is there a better way to go about this? (Remember, I don't want to redownload every time, only if it's the first time (or if it's been deleted)).

Comment: You asked a similar question before.  As I recall, a suggested answer was "Don't make your config data a Python script, make it a file in some data format that you can parse."  That is, if you just need to read data, don't *run* it, just *read* it.

Comment: Yep.  Just serialize your data in a sane format.  `csv`, `json`, `shelve`, `pickle`, any relational database...

Comment: `pickle` [is not sane](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~s/musings/pickle.html), though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you learn how to use JSON, so you can just have a file like this:

```
{<id>:<mac>,<id>:<mac>}
```

(Yes, it's similar to Python's `dict` and you can use it the same way with the right parser)